# ACTION_DELETE Android

Tags: android

There was a question concerning removal of appendices in the program. I use such code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;


public class dop extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dop);
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<ResolveInfo> list = (ArrayList<ResolveInfo>) pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list) {
    System.out.println("Installed Applications " + rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
    myList.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
    }
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
    listView.setAdapter(aa);

    }
    public void onListItemClick(
            ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:"+"some.package.to.remove"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

But the removal code doesn't work. What I not so do?

Comment: any interesting message in the logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onListItemClick()` is available only in `ListActivity` (and it's actually a *protected* member), so basically you're not overriding anything and that method is never getting called.

(to be sure you're overriding something, put `@Override` before that method, the compiler will complain if that's not an override and you'll know something is wrong there)

As you're building an `Activity`, you'll need to make it implement `OnItemClickListener`, and in `onCreate()` set this listener on the `ListView`:

```
public class dop extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
//.....
    public void onCreate(Bundle bndl) {
        //....
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(/*...*/) {
        // put here your click code
    }
}
```

Comment: Has made as have told, but removal doesn't occur:

Comment: @ghostged: hm, the removal intent code seems fine. Check if onItemClick() is getting called (put a `Log.d("...","onitemclick called");` or set a breakpoint at that line and see if when debugging it's reached. Note that in Android it's better practice to use Log instead of System.out.println)